How to cicle amount field in SAP when a grid is only detected like a SAPGuiWindow in UFT
I don't understand how can i cylce and read "amount" field on SAP GUI when i don't have a grid like an element, and i only have whole sap window thats deteced like  a SAPGuiWindow:

When i use an ObjectSpy to detect an column Title or Value, they are detected like:
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Visualizar partidas de_2").SAPGuiLabel("1.200,00").SetFocus
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Visualizar partidas de_2").SAPGuiLabel("Importe MC").SetFocus

And whole windows is detected like a:
SAPGuiSession("Session").SAPGuiWindow("Visualizar partidas de_2")

I can't find any method to use for cycle this supposted "grid" and read all values of mount.
